# C++ Unreal Engine encapsulate delegates

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm new to unreal engine and c++. I have a class in which I define a delegate with one parameter and a return type:

```cpp
DECLARE_DELEGATE_RetVal_OneParam(bool, FInteractionValidatorDelegate, APlayerController*)
```

I've added a property containing this delegate:

```cpp
FInteractionValidatorDelegate Validator;
```

And in another class I bind the delegate:

```cpp
SomeComponent->Validator.BindUObject(this, &AInteractable::IsValid)
```

This all works fine but I don't want to expose the delegate publicly thus I want to encapsulate it by adding a `BindValidator()` method to my component. What is the best method of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could write a function like this :

```
void yourComponent::BindValidator(UObject * obj, void(*func)(bool))
{
    Validator.BindUObject(obj, func);
}
```

but I recommend against doing this, first because passing functions' pointers will make errors coming from this hard to find (delegates are already enough obfuscation, with lots of macros and generated functions), also you will not be able to expose this to blueprints.

In UE4's way of doing things you could just pass a delegate as a `FName`
like so :

```
void yourComponent::BindValidator(UObject * obj, FName functionName)
{
    Validator.BindUFunction(obj, functionName);
}
```

Here it's the UE4 doing the functions' declaration matching.

Hope this helps!